# Workspace generated unreadable characters

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-flow

I am running a workspace on FME Server and I see that most of the columns have unreadable characters in them after running a workspace. I have not seen this before. Workspace is incorrectly writing data and creates duplicate records in the SDE writer. Here is a screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: What Version of FME Server are you using?

Comment: if FME 2020+ they use UTF8 https://community.safe.com/s/article/UTF-8-Names-FAQ-Encoding-in-FME looks like you need UTF-16?

Comment: I am using FME server 2022.0 and I created the workspaces in 2021, then I opened and saved those workspaces in 2022

Answer (score 0):

SAM, This problem was fixed for FME 2022.1 - get the latest from https://www.safe.com/support/downloads/